# function overloading in C++ not working when parameters differ by type

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, overloading, parameter-list

I know that overloaded functions in C++ can be differentiated by the number parameters, type and sequence as it says [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-function-overloading/).
However, when I tried the following code, I've got an ambiguity error but I don't know why since one of the parameters differs (and the sequence should not matter in this case):

```
class MyClass
{
    public:

    MyClass() {}

    void myMethod(char x, int y){
        cout<<"int"<<endl;
    }

    void myMethod(char x, float y){ //if the arguments are swapped, the function is not ambiguous anymore
        cout<<"float"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.myMethod('x', 1);
    obj.myMethod('x', 0.5);
}
```

Comment: the issue is it's considering `0.5` as double, not float. hence unable to overload properly

Comment: try `float y = 0.5; obj.myMethod('x', y);` it'll work fine since `y` is float variable

Comment: Please show the error you are asking about.  Does it look [anything like this](https://godbolt.org/z/xeqj1oPEf)?  Do you understand what the error is saying?

Comment: `0.5f` would be a proper float literal.

Comment: error: call of overloaded 'myMethod(char, double)' is ambiguous|

Comment: It worked. Thank you guys! Could you please provide me some good source of information about this topic. I mean when the compiler is interpreting some data types as others. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @Ady96 `0.5` is a `double`.  `0.5f` is a `float`.  Take a look at the [Literals section in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals).